# Electron micrographs, is it showing electrical charges?

Tags: optics

Are electron photographs showing electrical charges? Do electrically charged parts show up more (darker in the photo) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because the electrons interact mainly electromagnetically, all of their other interactions are negligible to that.

Electronmicroscope generate a 2D plot, essentially a matrix, mapping the picture we made. It depends on the imaging software, how it maps the values to greyscale colors.

Comment: This is incorrect - at least so far as "yes , electrically charged parts show up more"

Answer (score 0):

If you read the excellent discussions on the wikipedia page, you'll see that a transmission electron microscope works on the same principle as an x-ray machine: the image shows how many particles/photons made it through the subject.

Other techniques analyze the various secondary products produced by electron collisions with the subject, such as heat or X-ray emission.

The charge or lack thereof on the subject material has essentially zero bearing on the final image.